# VBA Code for SUMIF statement - Need to build-in additional conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'm trying to fumble my way through some VBA scripting. I found this code online that allows for a SumIf function to occur when a **single** condition is met. I would like to expand it to two maybe three conditions.

```
    Function SumIfVisible(rng As Range, condition, rngSum As Range) As Double  
Dim i As Long
 For i = 1 To rngSum.Count

If rng(i) = condition And rngSum(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
  SumIfVisible = SumIfVisible + rngSum(i)
End If
 Next I
End Function
```

To clarify, I would like to meet multiple **conditions** in multiple **ranges**. I.e. **Condition1** in *range* **D2:D200** and **condition2** and **condition 3** in **range H2:H200**.

Additionally, ranges may have **partial differing** values in the specific sense, but meet the condition holistically i.e **condition1 = "Jan", range D2:D200 contains dates such as "1-Jan,2-Jan,3-Jan" etc. All dates in the "" meet the condition.** SUMIFS do not allow for a truncated string selection for cell values. I.e. select every row that has "Jan" even though it contains other values like "1,2,3"

Please help!

Comment: The above code will sum only visible cells, do you want that also?

Comment: Do you have access to `SUMIFS()`?

Comment: Have you tried using the `SUBTOTAL` function in Excel? It can ignore hidden values and can be combined with `SUMPRODUCT` to create your conditional summing for visible rows only. That can negate the need for your UDF.

Comment: [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) may come in handy as well, perhaps, if you have XL2010 or >.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks mate, I bypassed that function for some reason... I think I got lost in trying to build INDEX and MATCH functions.

Comment: @Kyle - Though, after trying this further I remember my issue with SUMIFS. I need to make the conditions both relative to another cell (which can be done with SUMIFS) and discriminate certain elements in the string of data. I.e. Sum every row that meets the condition "January", though every row holds specific date values (1 January, 2 January, 3 January etc)

Comment: @clearguise if you edit your question to include sample data and expected output I'm sure we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data contains text and not dates formatted to look like `d-mmm`, this should get you started:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B2,A1:A2,"*Jan")
```

Or if you have actual dates:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B2,A1:A2,">=1/1/2016",A1:A2,"<=1/31/2016")
```

B1:B2 is the range to sum, and A1:A2 is the criteria range.

Note that `SUMIFS()` includes hidden rows, so if excluding hidden cells is part of your criteria you'll need `SUBTOTAL()` or `AGGREGATE()` as mentioned above.